# Check if elements in a vector are drawn exclusively from another vector

Tags: r, list, vector, iteration

I have an R list with numeric vectors of different lengths. Something like this.

```
l = list(a = c(0, 1, 2), b = c(0, 1), c = c(0, 1, NA), d = c(0, 1, 5))
```

I want to identify the vectors that have values of `0`, `1`, or `NA` and, therefore, can be converted to logical vectors. In the above example, I would identify vectors `b` and `c`.

To do this, I am going to attempting something like this.

```
is.logical.vector = lapply(l, FUNCTION_NAME)
```

But I'm not sure what function to use in place of `FUNCTION_NAME` (that's just a placeholder for illustrative purposes). I need something that can take a vector like `allowed = c(0, 1, NA)` and ensure that only the values in `allowed` are represented in the elements of a vector (like those in list `l`).

Do you know if such a function exists? Alternatively, do you know how I could construct such a function without an explicit `for` loop? Thank you in advance!

Comment: @AnandaMahto, that's true (no pun intended). But I want to identify vectors with values of 0, 1, or NA, to convert to logical vectors. I'm not interested in vectors with other values.

Comment: Something like `vapply(l, function(z) all(z %in% c(0, 1, NA)), logical(1L))`? (OR `lapply(l, function(z) all(z %in% c(0, 1, NA)))`.) According to your comment, you should also exclude "a" from the result.

Comment: @AnandaMahto, you nailed it! Would you mind making your answer a formal answer rather than a comment so that I can accept it? By the way, I find that `T` instead of `logical(1L)` saves on characters, but works just as well.

Comment: "I would identify vectors a, b, and c." c has a 2 in it, do you want to allow that or include only vectors that have *only* 0, 1, or NA?

Comment: @user3114046, good catch! Have edited the question appropriately.

Comment: @user2932774, answer added. I would suggest against getting into the habit of using "T" and "F" to represent `TRUE` and `FALSE`... Partly personal preference, and partly because "T" and "F" can be overwritten.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By the sounds of it, you are looking for a combination of `all` and `%in%`:

```
vapply(l, function(z) all(z %in% c(0, 1, NA)), logical(1L))
#     a     b     c     d 
# FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Alternatively,  you can use `lapply`:

```
lapply(l, function(z) all(z %in% c(0, 1, NA)))
```

---

FYI, `as.logical(5)` or even `as.logical(-5)` also evaluate to `TRUE`, so your condition "therefore, can be converted to logical vectors" doesn't *quite* match what you actually seem to be asking for :-)

Comment: Another one for the road: `mapply(identical, l, lapply(lapply(l, as.logical), as.numeric))`